# Enum vs As Const

Tags: typescript

What are the pros and cons of using `as const` over `enum`? Like slight performance advantages, etc.

```
enum Links {
    Link1 = 'test1',
    Link2 = 'test2',
}

const Links = {
    Link1: 'test1',
    Link2: 'test2',
} as const;
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Let's compare [string `enum`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) to [`const`-asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) object literals with [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) property values!

SUMMARY:

- the performance is the same
- an `enum` brings a named value, a named type, and a named namespace into existence, which needs to be done separately if you want that without an `enum`.
- a string `enum` is a nominal subtype of `string` that is not interchangeable with its string literal values.

---

We can dispense with performance first.  There is almost certainly no meaningful performance difference between them.  Both versions behave the same at runtime: you just have an object named `Links` with the two properties.  And I've never noticed a difference with the compiler either; it's fast either way.  If performance is an issue at all, your `enum`s are too big or you have too many of them.

---

Now for some actually noticeable differences.  Note that such differences could be seen as advantages in one situation but disadvantages in another.  It really depends on the use case.  So let's look at a string `enum` and see how closely we can approximate it without using an `enum`:

```
enum Links {
    Link1 = 'test1',
    Link2 = 'test2',
}
```

Declaring `Links` to be an `enum` brings a few things into scope:

- a *value* named `Links`; an object which exists at runtime and has string-valued properties `Links.Link1` assignable to `"test1"` and `Links.Link2` assignable to `"test2"`.
- a *type* named `Links`; the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the possible *values* of the `Links` object. As a type it only exists at compile time.  For example, you can write `interface Foo { link: Links }` to mean that a `Foo` must have a `link` property which is either `Links.Link1` or `Links.Link2`.
- a *namespace* named `Links` with exported *types* named `Links.Link1` and `Links.Link2`, which correspond to the types of the values named `Links.Link1` and `Links.Link2`, respectively.  For example, you can write `interface Bar extends Foo { link: Links.Link1 }` to mean that a `Bar` must have a `link` property which is exactly `Links.Link1`.  This sort of thing is handy for building [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).

You can simulate each of these yourself without declaring an `enum`, and get something which behaves quite similarly (but not identically) to a string enum both at runtime and at compile time:

```
const Links = {
    Link1: 'test1',
    Link2: 'test2',
} as const;

type Links = (typeof Links)[keyof typeof Links];

namespace Links {
    export type Link1 = typeof Links.Link1;
    export type Link2 = typeof Links.Link2;
}
```

So, one possible advantage to the `enum` syntax is: if you want to use `Links` as a value, a type, and as a namespace, this happens automatically; whereas to get the same effect without `enum` requires quite a bit of boilerplate code.  On the other hand, if you don't care about, say, the type or the namespace, you can write `const Links = {...}` and not bring these unneeded things into existence.

---

If the above `const`+`type`+`namespace` is not identical to an `enum`, what's the difference?

The compiler treats an `enum` as something like a special [*nominal*](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping#using-enums) subtype of `string`.  For the `enum`, the type of `Links.Link1` is assignable *to* but not *from* the string literal `"test1`":

```
const to: "test1" = Links.Link1; // okay either way
const from: Links.Link1 = "test1"; // error for enum, okay for const
```

So, if you want `Links.Link1` to be *completely interchangeable* with the string literal `"test1`", then you should stay away from `enum`.  On the other hand, if you want to enforce that the only way to get that `"test1"` value is by writing out `Links.Link1`, you should use an `enum`.

That means the ideal use for a string `enum` is one in which the values are mostly treated as *opaque*. If the user of an `enum` actually cares about its particular string literal values, it's an indication that you might not really want an `enum`.  For example, imagine I changed the `Links` definition to this:

```
enum Links {
    Link1 = '454353',
    Link2 = 'xxxyyyzzz',
}
```

If the rest of my code is happy with that change, it's because I only ever refer to the enum values by indexing into `Links`.  Any code that mentions `"test2"` directly would break, but code that mentions `Links.Links2` would continue to work.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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)

Comment: We're having this debate in my team. I think it's often preferable to have enum values _not_ be interchangeable with strings to avoid the risk of making a typo in the string. For example, if a function returns an object containing  `{link: "testt2" as const}`, TypeScript won't say anything. It will complain when I try to _use_ that value in a place that is expecting a `Link`, but often that error will happen far away from where the typo was actually made, making the typo hard to hunt down!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the performance it depends upon how you use it like bubble sort in some conditions and in other conditions insertion sort. You should use enums where data are inter-related with each other like typeOfUsers for login are

```
enum typeOfUser{
   owner='ower',
   employee='employee',
   admin='admin'
}
```

Where as const can be used for values which don't needed to be changed and if you want to apply same code as enum mentioned above you can do something like this.

```
export const typeOfUsers = ['employee', 'owner', 'admin'] as const;
export type typeOfUser = typeof typeOfUsers[number];
```

Enums restrict you to the necessary set of inputs, while constant strings allow you to use strings that aren't part of your logic. This ensures that you don't make a mistake by entering something that isn't in the domain when entering data, and it also improves the readability of the code.