# Weird behaviour of typescript when ENUM imported from another file

Tags: typescript, debugging

I have the following two enums in separate files:

```
// Variant.ts
export enum Variant {
  LINK = "link",
  LINK_OUTLINE = "linkOutline",
  ICON_ONLY = "iconOnly",
}
// ButtonEditType.ts - derived from above one
export enum ButtonEditType {
  ICON_ONLY = Variant.ICON_ONLY,
  ICON_TEXT = Variant.LINK,
  ICON_TEXT_OUTLINE = Variant.LINK_OUTLINE,
}
// printing the enum in the file where I imported it
console.log(ButtonEditType);
```

Here, the `console.log` above should normally print -

```
{
  "ICON_ONLY": "iconOnly",
  "ICON_TEXT": "link",
  "ICON_TEXT_OUTLINE": "linkOutline"
}
```

But, instead I get -

```
{
    "ICON_ONLY": "iconOnly",
    "iconOnly": "ICON_ONLY",
    "ICON_TEXT": "link",
    "link": "ICON_TEXT",
    "ICON_TEXT_OUTLINE": "linkOutline",
    "linkOutline": "ICON_TEXT_OUTLINE"
}
```

Live snippet - https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-eyycla

**I've 2 possible solutions** -

> - to make all the properties of `ButtonEditType` as plain strings instead of referencing from `Variant`
> - to keep both enums in same file

**but I can't use both of them because I want to make things consistent with my Project**

Can anyone please help me understand what's wrong when an enum is referenced from another file?

Comment: Uhhh, that's very strange. [Reverse mappings for enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) should only be created for *numeric* enum entries, not for string entries.  I think we need more information about what's happening here; I can't reproduce your problem in my own IDE (it displays the value you expected), and without a [mre] it's very hard to know what to say or do.  Could you [edit] to provide more details and clarity around your environment?  For example: what JavaScript code does your compiler produce for that enum?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, I've updated the question with live snippet & my latest findings.

Comment: Apparently this is a TS bug: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56206.  You might be able to turn off `—isolatedModules` and make sure your project compiles all at once (instead of per-file) to get the correct behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript generates [reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) at compile time for [computed members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#computed-and-constant-members) but not constant members. Moving `Variant` to another file changes the nature of its values from constant to computed.

I suggest you use [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) instead of enums if you wish to print out the values, as it has the same effect as enum without the extra reverse mappings.

```
import { Variant } from './Variant';

export const ButtonEditType = {
  ICON_ONLY: Variant.ICON_ONLY,
  ICON_TEXT: Variant.LINK,
  ICON_TEXT_OUTLINE: Variant.LINK_OUTLINE,
} as const;
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66864086/6730402) an answer comparing string enums to const-asserted object.

Comment: You might want to mention: This is due to a bug in TypeScript, as per [ms/TS#56206](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56206). Apparently it should be an error for isolated modules to initialize enums with imported values, but TS allows it, causing strange and incorrect JavaScript code to be emitted.